# Javascript function not working in JS file

Tags: javascript

I have an application that I am working on and have tried for hours to figure this out including various suggestions here. When I run the code inline it works fine. I don't like pasting the same code into my HTML twice so I created and external `.js` file and called it instead. When I call the `.js` file I get an `"("#" + panelName).addClass is not a function` error. When I run the code inline it works perfectly. I have to refresh the screen every few minutes and want to keep the state of the collapse panels so I write a flag into localstorage and then retrieve it when the page reloads. This should then set the panel state by setting the class. I am just not sure why it does not work.  I am new to JS so be kind :)

Here is the code.   The SaveState.js file works just fine.

```
   <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" onclick="SaveState('collapse1')">Station 1</a>
   </h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
   <script type="text/javascript"> var panelName = 'collapse1' </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       if (localStorage.getItem(panelName) === 'open') {
           $('#' + panelName).addClass('panel-collapse collapse in');
       }
   </script>

   @*<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/SetCollapseState.js"></script>  *@
   <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
   <div class="panel-body">Panel Body1</div>
   <div class="panel-body">Panel Body2</div>
   <div class="panel-body">Panel Body3</div>
   <div class="panel-footer" style=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: where is your #panelName? you are missing the id

Comment: it may not be working because your script can be loaded before jquery. just wrap your script into `$(document).ready`

Comment: @CharlieNg It's above in another script tag.

Comment: Where is the external JS file. Is it just before the `body` closing tag? If the script is being run before the DOM has loaded, the JS will show errors in this instance.
The `$(document).ready` might be the issue as well as mentioned by PerunnSS

Comment: Charlie Ng.  panelName is a variable I am using to collect the DIV ID and assign it so I can assign the class.

Comment: The external JS is just after the panel creation.   When it was anywhere else, like at the end before the body closing tag it would cause  the panels to flash.   Having the script run just after the panel creation seems to have resolved that problem.

Comment: @PerunSS....  Jquery is loaded in the Layout partial view that I am using that creates the head section.   It is called way before.

Comment: @PerunSS ...  Why would it work with the inline code vs the JS script if it was a (document).ready issue?   The code works.. just not when I call it from the JS file.

Comment: @Branden When inline code is there it is loaded as file is loaded, but when separate file is there, then browsers spawns multiple threads to load all files - usually around 10 threads, that may cause troubles. Usually when you use jquery, best way to use other JS is to wrap it around with `$(document).ready`

Comment: @PerunSS  Thank you.   The information that i had was a little misleading and what you say makes a lot more sense as to how it is functioning.  I thought the external JS file would function the same as the inline code.  I will give that a try.

Comment: @PerunSS.   So I wrapped the code how I thought it would need to be and it just doesn't seem to like the anonymous function and I am not sure how to set the state just after the HTML is rendered.   Here is the code I am using... still the same errors.. just more of them.                                                    $(function(){

    if (localStorage.getItem(panelName) === 'open') {
        ('#' + panelName).addClass('panel-collapse collapse in')

    }
});

Comment: What does @* ... *@ mean?

Comment: @Branden try like this:
$(document).ready(function(){
if ...
});

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the reference to addClass to work by putting in the $ before the div id ..... I am using Jquery and would REALLY like to know why this would make a different.   Thanks you all for you time.

function SetCollapseState(panelName){

```
if (localStorage.getItem(panelName) === 'open') {
    $('#' + panelName).addClass('panel-collapse collapse in')

}
```

};

Answer (score -1):

Make sure jQuery is included at the top of your script. And clean up the code a bit to match below:

```
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" onclick="SaveState('collapse1')">Station 1</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var panelName = 'collapse1';
      if (localStorage.getItem(panelName) === 'open') {
        $('#' + panelName).addClass('panel-collapse collapse in');
      }
    </script>
  @*<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/SetCollapseState.js"></script>*@
  <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
  <div class="panel-body">Panel Body1</div>
  <div class="panel-body">Panel Body2</div>
  <div class="panel-body">Panel Body3</div>
  <div class="panel-footer" style=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would throw a ReferenceError first, not an `addClass` is not a function error.

Comment: Thank you... I do no want to really have the IF statement in line with the code.   I call it 6 times within this one page so I would like it as an  external JS file to call passing in the var panelName that is why the code is messy and what I am trying to resolve.   You can see on the next line that the script is being called via SetCollapseState.js.

Comment: Then use `window.panelName` instead of `var panelName`

Comment: @Tallboy.... I tried that and it did not work.   Any other ideas?   The crappy part about this is that it all worked until I slept!